# How to stop autoplay video on button click and then start playing again on button click using js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

I have a video that autoplay onload in jquery. I want to stop the video playing on button click and after clicking another button to start playing the video

```
<video autoplay loop muted>
  <source src="promo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

This is a start I gave but it won't autoplay the video in the beginning

```
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo"); 

function playVid() { 
  vid.play(); 
} 

function pauseVid() { 
  vid.pause(); 
}
```

I want to autoplay the video on load page and stop the video on button click and play again on button click using javascript/jquery

Answer (score 0):

Use `vid.autoplay=true`

```js
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo"); 
var count=0;
function control()
{
count++;
if(count%2==1)
pauseVid();
esle
playVid();
}
        function playVid() { 
            vid.play(); 
        } 
        function pauseVid() { 
            vid.pause(); 
        } 
vid.autoplay = true;
vid.load();
```

```html
<video autoplay loop muted onclick="control()">
  <source src="promo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```